# Scrolling Web Drivers using Selenium Efficiently

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to search for another method of scrolling a web page properly. The reason why I need to scroll the web page is because 75% of the data are lazy loaded. Which means it would not show up until i scroll through it. I'm currently using a slow method as below

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/1.8);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/1.9);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2.0);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2.1);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2.2);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2.3);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2.5);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2.6);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2.7);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2.8);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2.9);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.0);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.1);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.2);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.3);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.4);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.5);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.7);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.8);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4.2);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4.3);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4.5);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4.7);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4.9);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/5.2);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/5.1);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/5.8);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3.7);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/50);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Any Advice on scrolling. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One nice method of scrolling with Selenium is sending spacebar presses to the body:

```
background = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("body")
for i in range(5):
    background.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
    time.sleep(1)
```

You could use similar code with Shift+Spacebar to scroll up, if desired.

As an aside, looping a specific number of times using `range` like this is probably a bad idea... it would be best to loop until some specific element is visible, if at all possible. This was just for the sake of example.

Comment: Hi Tetrinity, Many Thanks!